# The Effect of Gas Diffusion on Life

Tags: atmosphere, alternate-reality

Let's say world is completely flat (infinite flat world, think minecraft flatworlds) for the purposes of the question. The gasses of the world started out in a grid pattern, with each square being 10<sup>13</sup> miles squared, and the atmospheres being as thick as the Earth's. Each gas starts out in its own square but slowly diffuses with the nearby squares. 
[image]
If life formed at the center of a square consisting of Carbon Dioxide (simulating the early Earth), and another square consisting of Methane, would the diffusion of the two gasses kill the creatures originating from the carbon dioxide square, or would the diffusion be slow enough that the creatures would be able to adapt?

Comment: the gasses would diffuse to fast for any kind of evolution to occur towards the local conditions. the gasses would have long since mixed by the time life evolved to even have a metabolism to worry about.

Comment: What is gravity like? Are you applying external sources of gravity, or is the only source of gravity the gas itself? Also, when you say "As thick as the Earth's atmosphere, I assume that you mean STP (Standard Temperature and Pressure), the approximate pressure of Earth's surface and 0C, but I'd like to double check.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus The gravity replicates the earth, the reason isn't important though, and I do mean STP.

Comment: Why require an infinite flat plain?  Any large spheroidal planet's surface could be gridded this way, tho' you would need an army of Maxwell's Daemons to make the gases start out this way.

Comment: An infinite flat plane can't exist, for obvious reasons, in our galaxy. Even if you reduce to maybe 1e10 km-square, with some arbitrary thickness, there is no material or mineral which can hold that shape. It would very rapidly flow into a sphere, and shortly thereafter fusion would almost certainly initiate.

Comment: You realize that if the gravity replicates Earth's gravity, then the vast majority of the gas will be unaffected by that gravity, right?

Comment: Yes, but *for the purposes of this question*, imagine that it *could* exist. I'm afraid I see neither an answer nor a frame challenge here.

Comment: It could exist in our galaxy. one would just have to use active support.

Comment: If the plain is infinite and these two cubes (not squares btw, unless they're not tall) are the only ones on the plain then they would be quickly sucked into the surrounding vacuum.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The world is not in our universe, it's a flat plane extending forever.

Comment: @Muuski No, for each cube there is a different random gas, and they would cover the whole plane, but the most common would be Hydrogen, Helium and Oxygen (with helium being most likely uninhabitable). Also it was on a grid so I didn't know what to call it.

Comment: @NepthysX  but there is no such thing as "infinite" in any physical universe.  And I repeat - unless you magically change the properties of gravity (leading to changes in all fundamental forces via G.R.), the plain will collapse.  Period.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft yea. Gravity is based on particles and everything wants to fall in a planar shape. Different universe. So yeah, I did magically change the fundamental forces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing each gas is at one ATM, their [diffusion coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_diffusivity) should be in the 0.1 ~ 0.3 cm<sup>2</sup>/s range.

We can plug that into [Flick's second law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion#Fick's_second_law) to find out how fast they diffuse. It can be simplified to this form:

$$t = \frac{x^2}{2D}$$

Where $T$ is time,  $D$ is the diffusion coefficient, and $x$ is distance.

Assuming a general value of 0.2 for all gases, just for a thought exercise. Every second, they should diffuse to a range of:

$$1 = \frac{x^2}{0.4} → x^2 = 0.4 → x = \sqrt{0.4} → x = 0.632456... $$

So every second each gas might diffuse 63 cm into the surrounding squares.

Life as we know on Earth started one billion years after Earth formed. In one billion years, we have approximately 3.15 x 10<sup>16</sup> seconds. Taking into account 63 cm/s, that gives us a diffusion of almost 2 x 10<sup>18</sup> cm in all directions. Let's adjust that to 2 x 10<sup>13</sup> km. Remember, 1 km is approximately 0.62 miles.

So, by the time life is starting to form, each gas has diffused past their immediate neighbors and a fifth of the way through the next, in the orthogonal directions.

Once the planet is four billions and a half old, the diffusion will have gone much 4.5x times further.

Supposing you have a rule that any square cannot be neighbor to another square with the same gas, the distributions should be pretty mixed. And in any case, life will have had billions of years to adapt. Any creature should be able to thrive well and safe in the square it is from, and at the very least in its eight neighboring squares, and the neighbors of those as well.

Comment: Physics in the service of fantasy.  I love it.  ++

Comment: Thank you! This should make my world much more interesting...

Answer (score 7):

I guess your main concern is not diffusion. The gases have different densities (CH4 0,656 kg/m³, CO2 1.977 kg/m³). So as soon as the barrier is removed between the squares, CO2 starts to flow to the bottom and spread, CH4 goes to the top and spreads. Of course there will be some diffusion and turbulances, but it does not change the fact, that your lifeforms in the methane square are going to die quickly in a CO2 windstorm.

Comment: I dare not even think about the radon and uranium-hexaflourite gas cubes.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight if you spend a few weeks thinking about the uranium fluorides, the problem of the radon will go away.

Comment: I don't think that would happen. In our own atmosphere we find oxygen, carbon dioxide and nitrogen in the same layer. Each has its own density as well.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight lol it would probably be very rare but a scary thought nonetheless...